# Prevent sign in without invitation code in rails/devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Scenario addressed:  A visitor cannot sign in without a generic code to control user access during initial test of a website (Rails 5.1.6 with devise 4.4.3)

This is achieved by setting the controller as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:fullname, :invitation])
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:fullname, :phone_number, :description])
 end
end
```

and then I have adjusted the user model with:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

attr_accessor :invitation
validates :validate_invitation, presence: true, :on => :create

def validate_invitation
if self.invitation != "123"
   self.errors[:base] << "Enter a valid invitation code"
 end
end
```

When I proceed to the sign with a new user, it fails. The console returns the following:
 Parameters: {... "user"=>{"fullname"=>"Jone", "invitation"=>"123",...}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}

However the sign in is not validated because: "Invitation can't be blank"

I can't see the mistake.

Comment: Update:  I have solved the issue by adding to the user class the following     validation below "attr_accessor :invitation":
    validates :invitation, on: :create, presence: true, inclusion: { in: ["123"]}

and eliminated the def validate_invitation entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the user class the following validation below "attr_accessor :invitation": validates :invitation, on: :create, presence: true, inclusion: { in: ["123"]}

and eliminate the def validate_invitation entirely.